# Git: Сommit the file to several branches

Tags: git

I have three branches and I am working on one of them. I am changing the file, and I need to update this file in two other branches. Can I do this with Git or do I need to go to another branch and just copy and paste?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think the user deserves a downvote. This is not really how git works, but instead of downvoting, explain to him why this isn't a feasible question

Comment: Is the file in the same state in all three branches? Can you clarify why you need to do this please

Answer (score 2):

`commit` and `push` your changes in a single branch, and then create pull request for the other two branches on git (gitHub, gitLab.. etc) and merge it.

or use `git merge` for more info check [git-merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)

or use `git rebase` for more info check [git-rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

For futher details check the difference between the two [merging-vs-rebasing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing)

Comment: cherry picking the commit to the other branches would likely be more appropriate - there’s no indication in the question the branches share history, or that it’s desirable to pull _all_ changes from one branch into the others.